# button server OnClick event not being fired in Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to fix this bug from somebody else's code.  Basically, there's this button inside an iframe:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="doUpload" OnClick="DoUpload_Click" OnClientClick="alert('OnClientClick');"/>
```

on the .js file, this line is called:

```
$('#doUpload', this.getIFrameDocument()).click();
```

This works perfectly on IE and Chrome.  The server event handler "DoUpload_Click" gets executed with no problems, except on Firefox.  On firefox, the OnClientClick gets called but not the server side event handler.  I tracked it down to the iframe being invisible (display:none).

Now, any ideas how I can still execute the server handler while maintaining the iframe invisible?  An idea is to put the iframe on coordinates outside of the user's browser dimensions... but any other ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Why are you using a javascript event to trigger a server event?  The OnClick event should trigger a postback on it's own and the doUpload method should be called.

Comment: @rie819: could be used to validate any other input state before execute a server side function.

Comment: yeah... it's part of page that lets you upload certain kinds of files without reloading the page.  it's indirect, I agree... but it achieves the effect.

Answer (score 1):

maybe [this blog entry](http://thomas.net.nz/post/2009/03/25/FireFox-cannot-handle-OnClientClick-and-OnClick-event-at-the-same-time.aspx) will help you. But first, you could try to use a "`return true;`" after any javascript command called; the browsers event handler might suppress the server side execution if the client side method returned `false` - so if you don't have a return value at all, it might behave differently (beeing `false` by default, for example).

Both not tested, though.

Answer (score 0):

try Adding Form.submit trigger on your js client-side click event handler.